# Show that $R[x_1, ..., x_n]$ is a $R$-Algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra

In *Algebra* by Aluffi there is this:

> Definition 5.7. Let R be a commutative ring. An $R$-Algebra is a ring homomorphism $α : R → S $ such that $α(R)$ is contained in the center of $S$  .

And a few lines thereafter there is this:

> Important example: the polynomial rings $R[x_1, . . . , x_n]$, as well as all their quotients, are commutative $R$-Algebras.

I am confused!

1- By the definition given, an $R$-Algebra is a ring homomorphism not a ring. So how $R[x_1, . . . , x_n]$ is an $R$-Algebra?

2- How "all their quotients" (i.e. of $R[x_1, . . . , x_n]$) are $R$-algebras?

PS. I am very new in mathematics. I would highly appreciate a clear elucidation.

Comment: Well, your book may define an "$R$-algebra" as a ring homomorphism $R\to A$, but the usual "abuse of notation" is to just call $A$ an $R$-algebra.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, so what would be S and α here for both cases of R[x1,...,xn] and all their quotients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, we have $S = R[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]$. $\alpha$ is not mentioned at all, but implicitly understood to be the inclusion of $R$ into $R[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]$ as the constant terms. As mentioned in a comment above by Lord Shark, it is a common abuse of notation to just specify $S$ instead of the whole homomorphism $R\to S$ when there is a natural choice of homomorphism available.

Comment: Can $R$ be mapped to any quotient of $S = R[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]$ by inclusion? Could you give an example?

Comment: @71D It can be mapped into any quotient of $S$, as you can just compose maps $R\to S\to S/I$ to make a map $R\to S/I$. Again, there is a natural choice for map $S\to S/I$, so it may be taken as implicit. So it's not uncommon to see, say "The $R$-algebra $R[x_1, x_2]/(x_1^2 + x_2^2)$".